# How can I implement FormView into DetailView, django

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

I use Django based views. I have  one class that displays the object(DetailView) and now I want to add a form to the same page, as in the DetailView.

My views.py:

```
class CommentFormView(FormView):
    form_class = AddCommentForm
    success_url = '/'

class BlogFullPostView(CommentFormView, DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'full_post.html'
    pk_url_kwarg = 'post_id'
    context_object_name = 'post'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(BlogFullPostView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['comments'] = Comment.objects.filter(post=self.object)
        return context
```

Maybe, you understand - BlogFullPostView - display page, where I want to add form.
CommentFormView - view for comment.

My form:

```
class AddCommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ('content',)
        widgets = {
            'content': forms.TextInput(attrs={
                'class': 'form-control'
            })
        }

        labels = {
            'content': 'Content'
        }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AddCommentForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

So, in template, I try to add form:

```
<form method="post" action="" role="form">
     {{ form }}
</form>
```

And it does not display anything :(

What should I do?

Comment: Can you inspect your html and see if the `<form method="post" action="" role="form">` is there?

Comment: Yep! it is there: `<form method="post" action="" role="form">
            {{ form }}
        </form>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not try to mix logic for both usecase in a single view.

```
class BlogFullPostView(DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'full_post.html'
    pk_url_kwarg = 'post_id'
    context_object_name = 'post'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(BlogFullPostView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['comments'] = Comment.objects.filter(post=self.object)
        context['form'] = AddCommentForm(initial={'post': self.object })
        return context

class CommentFormView(FormView):
    form_class = AddCommentForm

    def get_success_url(self):
        # logic here for post url 


# full_post.html

<form method="post" action="{% url "comment_form_view_url" %}">
    {{ form }}
</form>
```